# How to save in json format with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/updateCoursesIn'); ?>">
    <input type="text" value="1" name="values">
    <input type="text" value="2" name="values">
    <input type="text" value="3" name="values">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Function in codeigniter:

```
public function updateCoursesIn($from = "") {
            $data['value'] = json_encode($this->input->post('values'));
            $this->db->where('key', 'courses');
            $this->db->update('frontend_settings', $data);
        }
```

I need to save these values via codeigniter in json format, like this:

```
["1","2","3"]
```

The function I created is not saving as I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `values` array, add `[]` to `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text" value="1" name="values[]">
<input type="text" value="2" name="values[]">
```

With such naming `$this->input->post('values')` will be an array and will be correctly encoded to json.